# 2 php functions have different utf-8 output in the same document

Tags: php, html, wordpress, encoding, utf-8

I have the following html with 2 php functions that render a PDF:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div>
Summary:<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'summary', true); ?>
</div>
<div class="post-content">
            Content:<?php utf8_encode(the_content()); ?>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

They both have the same content, but the output is different.

The summary prints:

> Summary: Let's go out

The content prints:

> Content: Let?s go out

This leads me to believe it is something in the call that is affecting the utf-8 decoding. Both database tables use: `CHARSET=utf8`

How can I get the content section to render properly?

Answer (score 0):

check if utf8 encode function can help http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: I added this but no change.